# Does Doctrine have a SYNC method like Laravel Eloquent to work with entities?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to update/insert and sync several objects in a many to many relationship.

There is a many to many relationship between A and B entities.

I have an array with the list of ids of **entity B** that i would like to insert in **entity A**.  The sync method will delete all the entities that aren't in the array.

If such method doesn't exist in Symfony, what is the symfony way to handle this situation??

Comment: This could be done with setting an array of "B" entities into entity "A". If you need to sync only with ids, you can create a service.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  But the rest of the logic:  Search for all old B entities, check if exist in the new array of Bs and remove them is embedded in the sync method of laravel.  Im trying to figure out  how to save me to research and write all that stuff.

Comment: FYI, Your question is about Doctrine, not about Symfony.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to update the title.

Comment: Seems its not possible to update the title.  The title should say:  Does **SYMFONY DOCTRINE** have a SYNC method like **LARAVEL ELOQUENT** to work with entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony does not have a function equivalent to SYNC.

A way to handle this is to add a public function to the entity A

```
    public function sync($ids, array $array_bs){
    //get all Bs
    $bs = $this->getB();        
    foreach ($bs as $b){
        $id = $b->getId();
        if (strpos($id,$ids)== false){
            //remove
            $this->removeB($b);
        }
        //add new child entities
        foreach ($array_bs $bs){
            $this->addB($bs);
        }
    }
    }
```